# CoC opt out - To War or Not to War

Tags: clash-of-clans

What happens to members who opt out of war, but are included? Do they not get to attack or be attacked?

I am a leader of a successful clan in CoC. Since the newest update we leaders and coleaders have the ability to handpick our best members to be either "IN" or "OUT" in the war.

Now, as a member, one of the new features is to allow "OPT OUT" or "IN" to wars.

When I as leader start a war, I get a new screen which lets me pick and I can still choose those members who have opted out, their shield is red instead of green. What happens to them in war?

Thanks, 
ICE

Answer (score 9):

members who chose to opt of war and just signifying their *preference*. Even if they choose to opt out of war, you can still select them, and they will be in war, able to attack and defend. Members opting out of war are just saying that they do not wish to be included.